# Start service as a privileged non-admin user giving Access Denied error

Tags: windows, windows-services

I install a service using

```
sc.exe create MyService binPath= c:\MyService\MyService.exe DisplayName= 'My Service' obj= NAM\NAMuser password= **** start= Demand
```

I also added the user **NAM\NAMuser** to the `Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Local Security Policy` in below policy:
- Act As A Part Of The Operating System
- Access This Computer From The Network 
- Log on As A Service

However, when I try to start the service as **NAM\NAMuser** using either `sc.exe start MyService` or `net.ext start MyService`, I got the following error:

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

or for `sc.exe` command:

```
[SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

What other permission/policy do I need to give user **NAM\NAMuser** for this to work?

I know some SO post recommends to start as an Admin, but in my case it's not possible to grant Admin privilege to that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to construct a Frankenstein of admin-related rights, you should grant the NAM\NAMuser account the right to start/stop the specific service.

[SubinACL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51625.subinacl-a-complete-solution-to-configure-security-permission.aspx) is a fine choice if you are working from the command line (see Scenario 5 in the link). Go for our free [Service Security Editor](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceSecurityEditor/) GUI utility if you prefer a point-and-click experience.

Comment: going with SubinACL :) The issue is one of the old users wasn't given permission by SubinACL and yet that user was still able to start the service without Admin right...